# Getting URL of Facebook profile picture in JSON

Tags: facebook, image, profile

I am pretty new to JS. I am looking for a high-res profile picture of Facebooks users using FB Graph API.

The following code:

```
var pictureData = $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/< Facebook profile ID >/picture?type=large&redirect=0&width=400");
```

delivers a JSON like:

```
{
   "data": {
      "height": 480,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/...",
      "width": 480
   }
}
```

How do I extract the value of 'url' out of this?

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Easy one:

```
var pictureURL = pictureData.data.url;
```